# import zig package from another zig package

Tags: zig

I can import an package in my executable with `exe.addPackagePath("name", "path")` and usae it with `const name = @import("name");`. Now I want to include the package in another package, but I don´t understand how. Can I create an object for the package to set addPackagePath() on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `addPackagePath`, create `Pkg` structs directly (this way you will be able to specify sub-depencencies), and then use `addPackage`.

Here's an usage example of `Pkg`:
https://github.com/zig-community/Zig-Showdown/blob/main/build.zig#L6-L62

And here's how the structs are added to the executable:
https://github.com/zig-community/Zig-Showdown/blob/main/build.zig#L112-L118

Answer (score 3):

In zig 0.11.0-dev.2317+46b2f1f70:

```
b.addModule(.{
    .name = package_name,
    .source_file = .{ .path = package_path },
});
```

- Example from https://github.com/zig-postgres/zig-postgres/blob/005fb0b27f2d658224a3c39b6e4536668d8ed9f6/build.zig#L25
- More info https://devlog.hexops.com/2023/zig-0-11-breaking-build-changes/

In zig 0.11.0-dev.1503+17404f8e6:

```
const pkg_postgres = std.build.Pkg{
    .name = "postgres",
    .source = std.build.FileSource{
        .path = "deps/zig-postgres/src/postgres.zig",
    },
};
...
exe.addPackage(pkg_postgres);
```

- https://zenn.dev/ousttrue/books/b2ec4e93bdc5c4/viewer/4a67f3#pkg.path
- https://github.com/capy-ui/capy/blob/ab6d8df7123f27ae814003a31c5fda6eb6c2acd0/build_capy.zig#L25

Comment: I'm getting: error: root struct of file 'Build' has no member named 'Pkg'
 const pkg_postgres = std.build.Pkg{

Comment: Have you seen this https://devlog.hexops.com/2023/zig-0-11-breaking-build-changes/?

Comment: You can see working example here https://github.com/zig-postgres/zig-postgres/blob/main/build.zig

Answer (score 1):

This has changed very recently (I'm on v0.11.0-dev.1929+4ea2f441d), packages are now modules, and the way to add them is like so:

Imagine you had a file structure like so:

```
/src/main.zig
/src/foobar/foobar.zig
```

And in `foobar.zig` you had

```
// src/foobar/foobar.zig

pub fn foo()[*:0] const u8 {
   return "bar";
}
```

add it to your build.zig as so:

```
const foobar_module = b.createModule(.{
    .source_file = .{ .path = "src/foobar/foobar.zig"},
    .dependencies = &.{},
});

exe.addModule("foobar", foobar_module);
```

and then in `src/main.zig`

```
const std = @import("std");
const game = @import("game");


pub fn main() !void {
    // Prints to stderr (it's a shortcut based on `std.io.getStdErr()`)
    std.debug.print("Foobar: {s}\n", .{foobar.foo()});
}
```

should print after `zig build` and running the executable:

```
Foobar: bar
```

See https://devlog.hexops.com/2023/zig-0-11-breaking-build-changes/#modules for more

Answer (score -1):

zig 0.12.0-dev.817+54e7f58fc:

```
const foo = b.createModule(.{.source_file = .{.path = "../foo/src/main.zig"}});
exe.addModule("foo", foo);
```